# Displaying image with different aspect ratio in ImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView of fixed Size 210*230 for movie Poster. the images coming from server for different movie are of different aspect ratio and size. How make all image good in that poster imageView. I need to keep the poster imageView of fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode) property on the `UIImageView`. If you don't want any of the images to be cut off, you probably want to use `scaleAspectFit` so you would do something like `myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here

1. Change the **contentMode** property of UIImageView to be **scaleAspectFit**. In this case, empty space would be shown inside image view if image view and image's **aspect ratio** is not same. If ratio is same, your image will fit perfectly inside imageView.

---

2. Change the **aspect ratio** of each image programatically to fit perfectly into the image view. Just google how to resize image in swift. I had done this my self, code is available on SO. Just search a bit.

Hope it helps